# Swift separate String into array of data split at certain characters

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I need to dissect a String into multiple parts to put into an array. The string needs to be split at a specific set of characters.

For example: If I need to split this string at each "{=" occurrence, the string:

```
"{=hello{=secondindex{=stuffhere"
```

would turn into an array like this:

```
["hello", "secondindex", "stuffhere"]
```

Help is very much appreciated, I thank you in advance.

Comment: If your string will always start with `"{="` `"{=hello{=secondindex{=stuffhere".components(separatedBy: "{=").dropFirst()`

Comment: @LeoDabus You're beautiful, exactly what I needed.